# how to compare two fields in python

Tags: python, match, field

I have a very basic question in python. I want to go through each line of the a csv file and compare to see if the first field of line 1 is same as first field of next line and so on. If it finds a match then i would like to put that field in an object1 else put that field in a different object2. Finally i would like to count how many of the fields in object1 vs object2. Can this be done in python? Here is a small example.

```
BRM_1   679 1929
BRM_1   203 567
BRM_2   367 1308
BRM_3       435     509
```

As you can see field1 of line1 is same as field2 of line2 and so that field BRM_1 should be place in object1 and BRM_2 and BRM_3 should be placed in object2. So the final numbers of object1 is 1 and object2 is 2.

Comment: You may wanna tag it as a python qn next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt bad when I saw this question unanswered. Don't know if you still need the answer but here we go. I assume that you know how to read files and make a list of lists from them

```
file1=[['a',1,2],['a',3,4],['b',4,5],['c',3,5]]

li1=[] #first obj
li2=[] #second obj
skip_next = False
file_len = len(file1)

for current_row_num,row in enumerate(file1):
    if skip_next:
        skip_next = False
        pass
    else:
        if current_row_num == (file_len-1):
            # alone
            li2.append(row)
        elif row[0]!=file1[current_row_num+1][0]:
            #current row belongs in obj2
            li2.append(row)
        else:
            # current row has same first col value as next row
            # append both to li1
            li1.append(row)
            li1.append(file1[current_row_num+1])
            skip_next=True

print "first obj\n"+str(li1)

print "second obj\n"+str(li2)
```

Outout looks like

```
first obj
[['a', 1, 2], ['a', 3, 4]]
second obj
[['b', 4, 5], ['c', 3, 5]]
```

I believe that's what you were looking for. If you didn't care about the order and just wanted to know if row had a counterpart, code would be much simpler.